# Javascript canvas is not filling in with the correct color?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I must be doing something very dumb, because I am very confused over what's going on. I am simply filling in a rectangle with a specified color, like this:

```js
const c = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#D53F2E";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
```

```css
.example {
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #D53F2E;
}
```

```html
<div>The canvas:</div>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>A div using the same color:</div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

As you can see, I am specifying the fill color to be `#D53F2E`. However, the rectangle (on my screen at least), appears to be filled with `#C04F34`.

The colors don't match! However, I just thought to check Firefox, and they *do* match there. Was there a regression in the latest Chrome or something? I'm just using the latest Chrome and Windows 10, with uBlock Origin. Is there a flag I should be setting somewhere to ensure the colors match exactly?

Comment: I can't repro on my side. No matter what colorProfile for the OS (macOS), monitor and flags. You may want to report this to https://crbug.com as this seem like a bug that the profile doesn't apply the same on the CSS content and on the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

While typing this question, I thought to check Firefox vs Chrome, and noticed the colors matched in Firefox. This lead me to google "inaccurate colors Chrome" and found a comment online with this solution:

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags`
2. Search for `color profile`
3. Find the option `Force color profile`
4. Change it from `Default` to `sRGB`

This fixed the issue for me. Chrome now renders the specified color.

I think the issue occurred because my monitor uses the "Cool" color setting, and Chrome adopted this from my monitor settings. This overrides that and renders the actual color, instead of using the color profiled one.

Comment: Very strange. Chrome (and other Chromium-based browsers I have installed) render the color correctly (according to the GNU Image Manipulation program) with default flags.

Comment: Are you saying this is specific to `canvas`, or a general problem regardless of how the color is rendered (for instance, the `div` I added to your question)?

Comment: I'm saying this question isn't even suited to stackoverflow if I'm being honest in hindsight. It was just a chrome flag causing the entire browser to render using the Cool color profile of my monitor instead of using the literal colors.

Comment: That's still weird the flag has effects on CSS and not on the canvas (or the inverse). What if you start your context explicitly as sRGB? `c.getContext("2d", { colorSpace: "srgb" })`